Question wrongly marked as opinion based. Why?
The following question was marked as opinion based. As a result, it was closed and the author deleted the post before I could even give a factual answer.
https://superuser.com/questions/1866778/can-someone-identify-potential-issues-with-my-hp-laserjet-pro-m402dn-printer
They give a photo which clearly shows that ink is not transferred to the paper, which means that the fuser doesn't get warm enough to burn the ink onto the paper.
Some people may mistaken the fuser for the drum and therefore say that it is clean, but the photo of the print itself tells the whole story already.
And if it were the drum, then the printer would have ink spots at the same places throughout the print.
So: too much ink, drum, too little, fuser.

Also, third party cart, not initially mentioned on the question. Self deletion aside, I mean we could reopen and close with a more correct close reason?

@JourneymanGeek what do you mean? I mean, if we're going to reopen it to close it again, there's no point. What is incorrect again?

The question had/has insufficient information to answer

@JourneymanGeek I disagree with that assessment, based on the photo clearly showing everything one needs to know to answer it. The question basically is: my printer does this. Why? They did come up with a possible reason: the cheaper toner, but they did provide a clear image that shows the problem very clearly with enough details to answer it without question, I think.

Actually, I looked at the first version of that question, and they stated that it printed the first few pages fine. Cheap ink can also cause this. I guess the question was vandalised by the edits.

@LPChip - They bought a used cartridge for the used printer. This information was not included in the question.  Furthermore, they asked if they should purchase a new one, but we can't tell them whether a new cartridge would solve the problem.

@Ramhound yes, that information was in the very first verison of the post, it got edited out and then edited back in with different and confusing words. Or rather, it was a new cardridge but one from a factory that creates cheap knockoffs.

@LPChip - It actually wasn’t in the first revision here it was only in a comment. It was only in the revision prior to the question being deleted

@Ramhound first line literally says: " and a new printer cartridge"

@LPChip - The “new cartridge” was one of those “new” used refurbished cartridges. That fact was only shared in a comment, only discovered because I asked, if the cartridge is new why do you suspect replacing it would change the behavior

@Ramhound ah. The question was closed already and all comments were deleted when I first saw it.

@LPChip - So the question was, “I purchased a refurbished cartridge, my printer isn’t working m, would replacing it solve my problem”. Now if the problem is the cartridge we can’t say for sure, unless someone knows it can’t be caused by the cartridge I suppose, but my suggestion was simply return these used products as not functioning properly.

I can't see the deleted post, but printers are relatively simple mechanical devices.
IF toner is not on the drum THEN
   check that there is toner
   fuser is getting hot enough
   drum is not worn out
   drum is not covered in lost paper or similar

etc etc, work backward.
These are not opinions, these are simple problem-solving suggestions and eliminating possibilities.  As such it is more likely a duplicate than an opinion.
Another possibility is OP solved their own problem and was too embarrassed to share that the cartridge still had a shipping seal in place or that it was a remanufactured cart..
If there's no dupe, it was eminently answerable based on your description and I'd try an answer.

The question was significantly void of information.  The author purchased a used cartridge but failed to mention that in the question body.

@Ramhound okay thanks I was not aware.  Yes that would absolutely be a significant fact worth editing into the question.   And... who would bother buying or selling a used toner cartridge?   Remans are quite cheap, and I've frequently found the consumable I need on our local ebay (trademe) even as new-old stock.

@LPChip They bought a “new” refurbished cartridge. They stated that in a deleted comment. The comment was deleted after I added, “FWIW, I bought a cheaper cartridge — one that uses recycled cartridges I think.” after “I've bought a used M402d and a new printer cartridge.” That is key info that the original question did not have. Thus why I edited it in.
